# Fractional Part usage

Tags: functions

The minimum value of $f(x)=\frac{1}{2{\{-x\}}}-\{x\}$ where $\{.\}$ represent fractional part is

(A) $n+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$, $n\in I$

(B) $n-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$, $n\in I$

(C) $n+\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}$, $n\in I$

(D) $n+\frac{1}{2}$, $n\in I$

My approach is as follow

$-x=[-x]+\{-x\}$ & $x=[x]+\{x\}$ but not able to proceed as the formula is geting complicated on solving

Also used $x=n+a$ where $a\in(0,1)$ and $x$ is not an integer

Comment: Can you find the minimum value of $g(x) = 1/(2x) - x$ on the interval $[0, 1)$? Note that the graph of $f(x)$ just looks like a bunch of translated copies of the graph of $g(x)$.

Comment: @AnnieCarter That's correct except that $\{-x\}=1-\{x\}$ (when $x$ is not an integer) so you need to look at $g(z)=\frac{1}{2(1-z)}-z$ over the interval $(0,1)$ where $z=\{x\}$.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis Quite right!